# Can I replace my range cord with one having larger conductors?

Tags: electrical, wiring, range

I want to move my 40A range. The cable is 2-8 + 2-10 on a 40A circuit with a 40A breaker. Problem is the 4ft cord is too short. Can I replace the cord with a 50A one (2-6/2-8 10ft)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the cable to your oven with a larger one but you cannot increase the breaker size. Check to make sure your new cable plug will fit into your existing outlet. You might have to change that too. Check with some additional stores, maybe even an electrical supply store, to see if you can get a longer 40AMP cable, and the shorter, the better.

Comment: If she changes the outlet to be 50A-capable, might that entice someone to install a 50A range at some point (which implies the new outlet would be against code)?

Comment: @Daniel This is a weak spot in the NEC.  NEMA doesn't spec a NEMA 14-40A receptacle,  NEC Table 210.21(B)(3) specifies that a 50 amp rated receptacle is the allowed to be connected to a 40A circuit.

Comment: @DanielGriscom Good concern. But **there's no such thing as a 40A socket/plug**, and 40A applications use the 50A plug, as NoSparksPlease discusses.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a 50A rated cord for a 40A appliance with a 50A receptacle on a 40A circuit.

Pay special attention to NEC 210.50(C) Appliance Receptacle Outlets. Appliance Receptacle Outlets...shall be installed within 1.8m (6 ft) of the intended location of the appliance.

You will probably need to install a permanent breaker lock out device in your electrical panel to comply with NEC 422.30/422.33 that allows a receptacle accessible through the drawer to satisfy the required disconnecting means.

Also check with the Installation Instructions of the range to see if it specifies receptacle location or cord length. Lab Listing (UL,CSA) is only valid when installed or used as instructed in the Installation Instructions.

You may need to and it would be cleaner to change the existing receptacle to a junction box and extend the circuit to the oven location.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're always allowed to use larger wires - no harm there.

However, 8/8/10/10 is perfectly adequate for a 40A range.  8 AWG is legal to 40A@60C and 50A@75C.  The neutral only has the oven light and clock, so #10 is wild overkill.  #10 grounds are legal up to 60A circuits.